# Jquery Auto-Complete Limited Search Results (JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using the FoxyComplete plugin with Jquery Auto-Complete to do a simple search. Everything is setup and working great but I'm finding the search results extremely limiting.

I use a big JSON file for all of my data and the problem I'm having is in the following case: Let's assume that my JSON file has the following description:

```
{
"title": "Brand new black car"
},
```

If a user searches "`black car`", he or she will get the result perfectly and the search is great. BUT, if a user search "`car new`", nothing comes up even though both keywords are in my JSON file.

Any help would be great. I poured through the Jquery AutoComplete docs and couldn't find a solution either. My Jquery autocomplete js is below:

```
;
(function ($) {

  $.fn.extend({
    autocomplete: function (urlOrData, options) {
      var isUrl = typeof urlOrData == "string";
      options = $.extend({}, $.Autocompleter.defaults, {
        url: isUrl ? urlOrData : null,
        data: isUrl ? null : urlOrData,
        delay: isUrl ? $.Autocompleter.defaults.delay : 10,
        max: options && !options.scroll ? 10 : 150
      }, options);

      // if highlight is set to false, replace it with a do-nothing function
      options.highlight = options.highlight || function (value) {
        return value;
      };

      // if the formatMatch option is not specified, then use formatItem for backwards compatibility
      options.formatMatch = options.formatMatch || options.formatItem;

      return this.each(function () {
        new $.Autocompleter(this, options);
      });
    },
    result: function (handler) {
      return this.bind("result", handler);
    },
    search: function (handler) {
      return this.trigger("search", [handler]);
    },
    flushCache: function () {
      return this.trigger("flushCache");
    },
    setOptions: function (options) {
      return this.trigger("setOptions", [options]);
    },
    unautocomplete: function () {
      return this.trigger("unautocomplete");
    }
  });

  $.Autocompleter = function (input, options) {

    var KEY = {
      UP: 38,
      DOWN: 40,
      DEL: 46,
      TAB: 9,
      RETURN: 13,
      ESC: 27,
      COMMA: 188,
      PAGEUP: 33,
      PAGEDOWN: 34,
      BACKSPACE: 8
    };

    // Create $ object for input element
    var $input = $(input).attr("autocomplete", "off").addClass(options.inputClass);

    var timeout;
    var previousValue = "";
    var cache = $.Autocompleter.Cache(options);
    var hasFocus = 0;
    var lastKeyPressCode;
    var config = {
      mouseDownOnSelect: false
    };
    var select = $.Autocompleter.Select(options, input, selectCurrent, config);

    var blockSubmit;

    // prevent form submit in opera when selecting with return key
    $.browser.opera && $(input.form).bind("submit.autocomplete", function () {
      if (blockSubmit) {
        blockSubmit = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    // only opera doesn't trigger keydown multiple times while pressed, others don't work with keypress at all
    $input.bind(($.browser.opera ? "keypress" : "keydown") + ".autocomplete", function (event) {
      // a keypress means the input has focus
      // avoids issue where input had focus before the autocomplete was applied
      hasFocus = 1;
      // track last key pressed
      lastKeyPressCode = event.keyCode;
      switch (event.keyCode) {

      case KEY.UP:
        event.preventDefault();
        if (select.visible()) {
          select.prev();
        } else {
          onChange(0, true);
        }
        break;

      case KEY.DOWN:
        event.preventDefault();
        if (select.visible()) {
          select.next();
        } else {
          onChange(0, true);
        }
        break;

      case KEY.PAGEUP:
        event.preventDefault();
        if (select.visible()) {
          select.pageUp();
        } else {
          onChange(0, true);
        }
        break;

      case KEY.PAGEDOWN:
        event.preventDefault();
        if (select.visible()) {
          select.pageDown();
        } else {
          onChange(0, true);
        }
        break;

        // matches also semicolon
      case options.multiple && $.trim(options.multipleSeparator) == "," && KEY.COMMA:
      case KEY.TAB:
      case KEY.RETURN:
        if (selectCurrent()) {
          // stop default to prevent a form submit, Opera needs special handling
          event.preventDefault();
          blockSubmit = true;
          return false;
        }
        break;

      case KEY.ESC:
        select.hide();
        break;

      default:
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(onChange, options.delay);
        break;
      }
    }).focus(function () {
      // track whether the field has focus, we shouldn't process any
      // results if the field no longer has focus
      hasFocus++;
    }).blur(function () {
      hasFocus = 0;
      if (!config.mouseDownOnSelect) {
        hideResults();
      }
    }).click(function () {
      // show select when clicking in a focused field
      if (hasFocus++ > 1 && !select.visible()) {
        onChange(0, true);
      }
    }).bind("search", function () {
      // TODO why not just specifying both arguments?
      var fn = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : null;

      function findValueCallback(q, data) {
        var result;
        if (data && data.length) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].result.toLowerCase() == q.toLowerCase()) {
              result = data[i];
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (typeof fn == "function") fn(result);
        else $input.trigger("result", result && [result.data, result.value]);
      }
      $.each(trimWords($input.val()), function (i, value) {
        request(value, findValueCallback, findValueCallback);
      });
    }).bind("flushCache", function () {
      cache.flush();
    }).bind("setOptions", function () {
      $.extend(options, arguments[1]);
      // if we've updated the data, repopulate
      if ("data" in arguments[1]) cache.populate();
    }).bind("unautocomplete", function () {
      select.unbind();
      $input.unbind();
      $(input.form).unbind(".autocomplete");
    });


    function selectCurrent() {
      var selected = select.selected();
      if (!selected) return false;

      var v = selected.result;
      previousValue = v;

      if (options.multiple) {
        var words = trimWords($input.val());
        if (words.length > 1) {
          var seperator = options.multipleSeparator.length;
          var cursorAt = $(input).selection().start;
          var wordAt, progress = 0;
          $.each(words, function (i, word) {
            progress += word.length;
            if (cursorAt <= progress) {
              wordAt = i;
              return false;
            }
            progress += seperator;
          });
          words[wordAt] = v;
          // TODO this should set the cursor to the right position, but it gets overriden somewhere
          //$.Autocompleter.Selection(input, progress + seperator, progress + seperator);
          v = words.join(options.multipleSeparator);
        }
        v += options.multipleSeparator;
      }

      $input.val(v);
      hideResultsNow();
      $input.trigger("result", [selected.data, selected.value]);
      return true;
    }

    function onChange(crap, skipPrevCheck) {
      if (lastKeyPressCode == KEY.DEL) {
        select.hide();
        return;
      }

      var currentValue = $input.val();

      if (!skipPrevCheck && currentValue == previousValue) return;

      previousValue = currentValue;

      currentValue = lastWord(currentValue);
      if (currentValue.length >= options.minChars) {
        $input.addClass(options.loadingClass);
        if (!options.matchCase) currentValue = currentValue.toLowerCase();
        request(currentValue, receiveData, hideResultsNow);
      } else {
        stopLoading();
        select.hide();
      }
    };

    function trimWords(value) {
      if (!value) return [""];
      if (!options.multiple) return [$.trim(value)];
      return $.map(value.split(options.multipleSeparator), function (word) {
        return $.trim(value).length ? $.trim(word) : null;
      });
    }

    function lastWord(value) {
      if (!options.multiple) return value;
      var words = trimWords(value);
      if (words.length == 1) return words[0];
      var cursorAt = $(input).selection().start;
      if (cursorAt == value.length) {
        words = trimWords(value)
      } else {
        words = trimWords(value.replace(value.substring(cursorAt), ""));
      }
      return words[words.length - 1];
    }

    // fills in the input box w/the first match (assumed to be the best match)
    // q: the term entered
    // sValue: the first matching result
    function autoFill(q, sValue) {
      // autofill in the complete box w/the first match as long as the user hasn't entered in more data
      // if the last user key pressed was backspace, don't autofill
      if (options.autoFill && (lastWord($input.val()).toLowerCase() == q.toLowerCase()) && lastKeyPressCode != KEY.BACKSPACE) {
        // fill in the value (keep the case the user has typed)
        $input.val($input.val() + sValue.substring(lastWord(previousValue).length));
        // select the portion of the value not typed by the user (so the next character will erase)
        $(input).selection(previousValue.length, previousValue.length + sValue.length);
      }
    };

    function hideResults() {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(hideResultsNow, 200);
    };

    function hideResultsNow() {
      var wasVisible = select.visible();
      select.hide();
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      stopLoading();
      if (options.mustMatch) {
        // call search and run callback
        $input.search(

        function (result) {
          // if no value found, clear the input box
          if (!result) {
            if (options.multiple) {
              var words = trimWords($input.val()).slice(0, - 1);
              $input.val(words.join(options.multipleSeparator) + (words.length ? options.multipleSeparator : ""));
            } else {
              $input.val("");
              $input.trigger("result", null);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };

    function receiveData(q, data) {
      if (data && data.length && hasFocus) {
        stopLoading();
        select.display(data, q);
        autoFill(q, data[0].value);
        select.show();
      } else {
        hideResultsNow();
      }
    };

    function request(term, success, failure) {
      if (!options.matchCase) term = term.toLowerCase();
      var data = cache.load(term);
      // recieve the cached data
      if (data && data.length) {
        success(term, data);
        // if an AJAX url has been supplied, try loading the data now
      } else if ((typeof options.url == "string") && (options.url.length > 0)) {

        var extraParams = {
          timestamp: +new Date()
        };
        $.each(options.extraParams, function (key, param) {
          extraParams[key] = typeof param == "function" ? param() : param;
        });

        $.ajax({
          // try to leverage ajaxQueue plugin to abort previous requests
          mode: "abort",
          // limit abortion to this input
          port: "autocomplete" + input.name,
          dataType: options.dataType,
          url: options.url,
          data: $.extend({
            q: lastWord(term),
            limit: options.max
          }, extraParams),
          success: function (data) {
            var parsed = options.parse && options.parse(data) || parse(data);
            cache.add(term, parsed);
            success(term, parsed);
          }
        });
      } else {
        // if we have a failure, we need to empty the list -- this prevents the the [TAB] key from selecting the last successful match
        select.emptyList();
        failure(term);
      }
    };

    function parse(data) {
      var parsed = [];
      var rows = data.split("\n");
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = $.trim(rows[i]);
        if (row) {
          row = row.split("|");
          parsed[parsed.length] = {
            data: row,
            value: row[0],
            result: options.formatResult && options.formatResult(row, row[0]) || row[0]
          };
        }
      }
      return parsed;
    };

    function stopLoading() {
      $input.removeClass(options.loadingClass);
    };

  };

  $.Autocompleter.defaults = {
    inputClass: "ac_input",
    resultsClass: "ac_results",
    loadingClass: "ac_loading",
    minChars: 1,
    delay: 400,
    matchCase: false,
    matchSubset: true,
    matchContains: false,
    cacheLength: 10,
    max: 100,
    mustMatch: false,
    extraParams: {},
    selectFirst: true,
    formatItem: function (row) {
      return row[0];
    },
    formatMatch: null,
    autoFill: false,
    width: 0,
    multiple: false,
    multipleSeparator: ", ",
    highlight: function (value, term) {
      return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>");
    },
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 180
  };

  $.Autocompleter.Cache = function (options) {

    var data = {};
    var length = 0;

    function matchSubset(s, sub) {
      if (!options.matchCase) s = s.toLowerCase();
      var i = s.indexOf(sub);
      if (options.matchContains == "word") {
        i = s.toLowerCase().search("\\b" + sub.toLowerCase());
      }
      if (i == -1) return false;
      return i == 0 || options.matchContains;
    };

    function add(q, value) {
      if (length > options.cacheLength) {
        flush();
      }
      if (!data[q]) {
        length++;
      }
      data[q] = value;
    }

    function populate() {
      if (!options.data) return false;
      // track the matches
      var stMatchSets = {},
      nullData = 0;

      // no url was specified, we need to adjust the cache length to make sure it fits the local data store
      if (!options.url) options.cacheLength = 1;

      // track all options for minChars = 0
      stMatchSets[""] = [];

      // loop through the array and create a lookup structure
      for (var i = 0, ol = options.data.length; i < ol; i++) {
        var rawValue = options.data[i];
        // if rawValue is a string, make an array otherwise just reference the array
        rawValue = (typeof rawValue == "string") ? [rawValue] : rawValue;

        var value = options.formatMatch(rawValue, i + 1, options.data.length);
        if (value === false) continue;

        var firstChar = value.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
        // if no lookup array for this character exists, look it up now
        if (!stMatchSets[firstChar]) stMatchSets[firstChar] = [];

        // if the match is a string
        var row = {
          value: value,
          data: rawValue,
          result: options.formatResult && options.formatResult(rawValue) || value
        };

        // push the current match into the set list
        stMatchSets[firstChar].push(row);

        // keep track of minChars zero items
        if (nullData++ < options.max) {
          stMatchSets[""].push(row);
        }
      };

      // add the data items to the cache
      $.each(stMatchSets, function (i, value) {
        // increase the cache size
        options.cacheLength++;
        // add to the cache
        add(i, value);
      });
    }

    // populate any existing data
    setTimeout(populate, 25);

    function flush() {
      data = {};
      length = 0;
    }

    return {
      flush: flush,
      add: add,
      populate: populate,
      load: function (q) {
        if (!options.cacheLength || !length) return null;
        /* 
         * if dealing w/local data and matchContains than we must make sure
         * to loop through all the data collections looking for matches
         */
        if (!options.url && options.matchContains) {
          // track all matches
          var csub = [];
          // loop through all the data grids for matches
          for (var k in data) {
            // don't search through the stMatchSets[""] (minChars: 0) cache
            // this prevents duplicates
            if (k.length > 0) {
              var c = data[k];
              $.each(c, function (i, x) {
                // if we've got a match, add it to the array
                if (matchSubset(x.value, q)) {
                  csub.push(x);
                }
              });
            }
          }
          return csub;
        } else
        // if the exact item exists, use it
        if (data[q]) {
          return data[q];
        } else if (options.matchSubset) {
          for (var i = q.length - 1; i >= options.minChars; i--) {
            var c = data[q.substr(0, i)];
            if (c) {
              var csub = [];
              $.each(c, function (i, x) {
                if (matchSubset(x.value, q)) {
                  csub[csub.length] = x;
                }
              });
              return csub;
            }
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    };
  };

  $.Autocompleter.Select = function (options, input, select, config) {
    var CLASSES = {
      ACTIVE: "ac_over"
    };

    var listItems,
    active = -1,
      data,
      term = "",
      needsInit = true,
      element,
      list;

    // Create results
    function init() {
      if (!needsInit) return;
      element = $("<div/>").hide().addClass(options.resultsClass).css("position", "absolute")
      //.attr('id', 'benjamin')
      .appendTo(document.body);

      list = $("<ul/>").appendTo(element).mouseover(function (event) {
        if (target(event).nodeName && target(event).nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'LI') {
          active = $("li", list).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE).index(target(event));
          $(target(event)).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        }
      }).click(function (event) {
        $(target(event)).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        select();
        // TODO provide option to avoid setting focus again after selection? useful for cleanup-on-focus
        input.focus();
        return false;
      }).mousedown(function () {
        config.mouseDownOnSelect = true;
      }).mouseup(function () {
        config.mouseDownOnSelect = false;
      });

      if (options.width > 0) element.css("width", options.width);

      needsInit = false;
    }

    function target(event) {
      var element = event.target;
      while (element && element.tagName != "LI")
      element = element.parentNode;
      // more fun with IE, sometimes event.target is empty, just ignore it then
      if (!element) return [];
      return element;
    }

    function moveSelect(step) {
      listItems.slice(active, active + 1).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
      movePosition(step);
      var activeItem = listItems.slice(active, active + 1).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
      if (options.scroll) {
        var offset = 0;
        listItems.slice(0, active).each(function () {
          offset += this.offsetHeight;
        });
        if ((offset + activeItem[0].offsetHeight - list.scrollTop()) > list[0].clientHeight) {
          list.scrollTop(offset + activeItem[0].offsetHeight - list.innerHeight());
        } else if (offset < list.scrollTop()) {
          list.scrollTop(offset);
        }
      }
    };

    function movePosition(step) {
      active += step;
      if (active < 0) {
        active = listItems.size() - 1;
      } else if (active >= listItems.size()) {
        active = 0;
      }
    }

    function limitNumberOfItems(available) {
      return options.max && options.max < available ? options.max : available;
    }

    function fillList() {
      list.empty();
      var max = limitNumberOfItems(data.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (!data[i]) continue;
        var formatted = options.formatItem(data[i].data, i + 1, max, data[i].value, term);
        if (formatted === false) continue;
        var li = $("<li/>").html(options.highlight(formatted, term)).addClass(i % 2 == 0 ? "ac_even" : "ac_odd").appendTo(list)[0];
        $.data(li, "ac_data", data[i]);
      }
      listItems = list.find("li");
      if (options.selectFirst) {
        listItems.slice(0, 1).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        active = 0;
      }
      // apply bgiframe if available
      if ($.fn.bgiframe) list.bgiframe();
    }

    return {
      display: function (d, q) {
        init();
        data = d;
        term = q;
        fillList();
      },
      next: function () {
        moveSelect(1);
      },
      prev: function () {
        moveSelect(-1);
      },
      pageUp: function () {
        if (active != 0 && active - 8 < 0) {
          moveSelect(-active);
        } else {
          moveSelect(-8);
        }
      },
      pageDown: function () {
        if (active != listItems.size() - 1 && active + 8 > listItems.size()) {
          moveSelect(listItems.size() - 1 - active);
        } else {
          moveSelect(8);
        }
      },
      hide: function () {
        element && element.hide();
        listItems && listItems.removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        active = -1;
      },
      visible: function () {
        return element && element.is(":visible");
      },
      current: function () {
        return this.visible() && (listItems.filter("." + CLASSES.ACTIVE)[0] || options.selectFirst && listItems[0]);
      },
      show: function () {
        var offset = $(input).offset();
        element.css({
          width: typeof options.width == "string" || options.width > 0 ? options.width : $(input).width(),
          top: offset.top + input.offsetHeight,
          left: offset.left
        }).show();
        if (options.scroll) {
          list.scrollTop(0);
          list.css({
            maxHeight: options.scrollHeight,
            overflow: 'auto'
          });

          if ($.browser.msie && typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === "undefined") {
            var listHeight = 0;
            listItems.each(function () {
              listHeight += this.offsetHeight;
            });
            var scrollbarsVisible = listHeight > options.scrollHeight;
            list.css('height', scrollbarsVisible ? options.scrollHeight : listHeight);
            if (!scrollbarsVisible) {
              // IE doesn't recalculate width when scrollbar disappears
              listItems.width(list.width() - parseInt(listItems.css("padding-left")) - parseInt(listItems.css("padding-right")));
            }
          }

        }
      },
      selected: function () {
        var selected = listItems && listItems.filter("." + CLASSES.ACTIVE).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        return selected && selected.length && $.data(selected[0], "ac_data");
      },
      emptyList: function () {
        list && list.empty();
      },
      unbind: function () {
        element && element.remove();
      }
    };
  };

  $.fn.selection = function (start, end) {
    if (start !== undefined) {
      return this.each(function () {
        if (this.createTextRange) {
          var selRange = this.createTextRange();
          if (end === undefined || start == end) {
            selRange.move("character", start);
            selRange.select();
          } else {
            selRange.collapse(true);
            selRange.moveStart("character", start);
            selRange.moveEnd("character", end);
            selRange.select();
          }
        } else if (this.setSelectionRange) {
          this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.selectionStart) {
          this.selectionStart = start;
          this.selectionEnd = end;
        }
      });
    }
    var field = this[0];
    if (field.createTextRange) {
      var range = document.selection.createRange(),
        orig = field.value,
        teststring = "<->",
        textLength = range.text.length;
      range.text = teststring;
      var caretAt = field.value.indexOf(teststring);
      field.value = orig;
      this.selection(caretAt, caretAt + textLength);
      return {
        start: caretAt,
        end: caretAt + textLength
      }
    } else if (field.selectionStart !== undefined) {
      return {
        start: field.selectionStart,
        end: field.selectionEnd
      }
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```